# Athena: Query exhausted resources at this scale factor

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, amazon-athena

I have two dataframe dumps, lets call them `df1` and `df2`, residing in s3 in the form of json files (an output of, say, spark).

Both of the datasets contain a `polygon` field which contains a WKT Polygon.

`df1` is > 1TB, `df2` is ~3GB.

I'm trying to join these two datasets, such that the polygons intersect. However, it seems like Athena is not able to handle such join queries, failing with the error:

`Query exhausted resources at this scale factor`

### Query:

```
select count(*) from
df1
left join df2
on st_intersects(df1.polygon, df2.polygon)
limit 1;
```

Non-geo queries work absolutely fine though.
Single-point geo queries work fine as well:

```
select (st_area(st_intersection(polygon, ST_Point(-64.0059731, 27.7143528))) / st_area(polygon))
from df1
where st_contains(polygon, ST_Point(-64.0059731, 27.7143528));
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Is there a identifiable pattern for Athena, for which stuff works?

Comment: For the record, Presto gained support for Spatial join in 0.197 (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.197.html). Are you constrained to use Athena, which is (currently) based on Presto 0.172?

Comment: I faced this error a few months back too. However , it automatically stopped occuring when I tried after some time - half an hour or so. Is it still the same ?

Comment: @ReshamWadhwa wow that sounds tricky. But yeah I did try for sometime / days, I suppose partitioning would help, which I'll try and update this.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen thanks for the pointer, I guess I'll back off to presto / geomesa if this does not work. However, the only draw to using athena is the serverless-ness, I don't want to maintain infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto [supports Spatial queries since version 0.197](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.197.html).
[Athena is based on Presto 0.172](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html), so it (currently) cannot execute such queries efficiently.

Comment: You probably mean this PR: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/9474

Answer (score 0):

If you have the coordinate of the center of each polygon and if the polygons have the same radius, you could use the haversine function to measure the distance between the center of the 2 polygons and, compared with the standard radius, identify the ones that intersect.